# Can I access the MsBuildWorkspace from within a MsBuild Task class?

Tags: msbuild, roslyn

As far as I understand, Roslyn have introduced the concept of Workspaces. One implementation of Workspaces is the MsBuildWorkspace.

My question is, can I from within a custom build task access a Roslyn Workspace representing the project being built?

I suspect that this is the purpose of MsBuildWorkspace. If so, can I access this workspace from the `Execute` method in my custom task (derived from `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task`)?

In case you are wondering why, I need to traverse other aspects of the project being built.
It is not enough for me to have access to the specific input file of the task to generate the output.

Comment: Have you found a solution? This is insane, I don't even want to build, I want to use Roslyn for code analysis in a build task, but I get the error opening the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect that this is the purpose of MsBuildWorkspace

No.
The point of `MsBuildWorkspace` is to parse an MSBuild project or solution into a Roslyn workspace.

MSBuild itself (which is what actually runs your MSBuild task) does not use Roslyn at all (it just invokes the C# compilation task, which is implemented using Roslyn), so there is no existing `MsBuildWorkspace` that you could fetch.

<strike>You could create your own `MsBuildWorkspace` from the project file.</strike>

Comment: And the technical reason it doesn't work: MSBuildWorkspace behind the scenes starts a build to figure out what's in the project. This doesn't work well when a build is already happening.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: You mean the reason that there is no way to get the original `MsBuildWorkspace` when the build is initiated by Roslyn?

Comment: Simpler reason: Not all builds are initiated by Roslyn.

Comment: It's not just that you can't access some mythical original MsBuildWorkspace, it's that trying to construct *any* MsBuildWorkspace will trigger a deadlock.

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson: I did not know that.  Why? Does MSBuild use non-reentrancy-safe global state (eek)?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You can't have two builds running against the same project at once. Even if you used a thread-safe object, the entire concept is still broken: what if you have two instances of a build task writing to the same file at once? The only way to "fix" this is to reimagine a fundamentally different build system.

Comment: Added a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084013/roslyn-how-to-load-an-existing-project-outside-of-visual-studio