# Roslyn: How to load an existing project outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn, msbuild-task, visual-studio-2015

As written in this question:

[Can I access the MsBuildWorkspace from within a MsBuild Task class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948207/can-i-access-the-msbuildworkspace-from-within-a-msbuild-task-class)

You cannot use `MSBuildWorkspace` from an MSBuild task for the same project. However, the only 2 other options are `VisualStudioWorkspace` and `AdhocWorkspace`.

Does this mean that there's no option for loading a project from an MSBuild task?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to *achieve*. Presumably you want to do something with the project after loading it - what is that "something"?

Comment: I just want to load a project and it's metadata (and do some analysis on them afterwards). Since I'm not loading the current solution within visual studio, the alternative is `MSBuildWorkspace`. But unfortunately this is not possible if you're running from an MSBuild task. In this scenario you can only use `CommandLineProject`.

Comment: What happens if you try to use it in a build task? You definitely don't have to be in VS to use it - I have unit tests which do so, for example. They're run on a CI server via the NUnit console runner...

Comment: The problem is that MSBuildWorkspace triggers a build for that project. And MSBuildWorkspace will start complaining about the fact that there's already a build running for that project. It's working fine in your case since the task is not run as part of MSBuild but through NUnit console runner.

Comment: Right - it sounds like the simplest approach may be to copy the project file to a new temporary file, and load *that* in an `MSBuildWorkspace` - removing the task as you go, to avoid recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution in this post:
[Roslyn: workspace loads in console application but not in msbuild task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052115/roslyn-workspace-loads-in-console-application-but-not-in-msbuild-task/15337218#15337218)

It still feels as a workaround, however it's working. There's actually a benefit to it in that the project doesn't have to be compiled anymore in order to load the project!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Project from a set command line arguments using `CommandLineProject.CreateProjectInfo`, so if you have the csc command line, you can use that.

Comment: Is there an API function for that?

Comment: Added it to the answer.

Comment: This is not really a solution I'm afraid, while it would be possible to get them, that would more or less mean that the project file needs to be parsed. From the sources however, this seems to be the only way to get to a projectinfo instance without using MSBuildWorkspace or VisualStudioWorkspace...